# make -j and #pragma GCC diagnostic

Tags: c++, gcc

Let's say  I add the following to A.cpp

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-parameter"
<code with unused parameters here>
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

Then I build with "make -j." If "A.cpp" and "some_other_file_with_no_pragma.cpp" get built in parallel, will the `#pragma` above apply to both files? I would think not, but can't find a definitive answer.

Comment: This seems like a good place for the [maybe_unused](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/maybe_unused)  attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not unless you are doing some really weird stuff in your Makefile.

Compiler compiles each translation unit(`.cpp`+included `.hpp`) independently, meaning each pragma only applies to this one translation unit.

Running `make -jN` will execute `N` rules in parallel, each (line) in a separate shell process. Resulting in up to `N` parallel compilers which will not interfere with each other.

Answer (score 0):

> … *will the `#pragma` above apply to both files?*

No. From [the documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html) (bold emphasis mine):

> Note that these pragmas override any command-line options. GCC keeps
> track of the location of each pragma, and issues diagnostics
> ***according to the state as of that point in the source file***. Thus, pragmas occurring after a line do not affect diagnostics caused
> by that line.